# Sitemap for Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml-parsing, sitemap, sitemap-generator-gem

I have installed the `sitemap_generator` gem and successfully implemented it.
Now i have a **sitemap.xml.gz** in my `public/sitemaps` folder.

I want to show sitemap on my website like this.[image]

How to do that?

Comment: If you have your site map in a XML File, why don't you read it from it?

Comment: i have sitemap in xml.gz file and i want to show this on my view.

Comment: Then read it in, parse it with something like [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) and make a view to present it.

Comment: How to do that? Can anyone provide me the code please?

Comment: Take a look at nokogiri gem as @tadman said...